# Regex 301 RedirectMatch in .htaccess not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Some time ago my WordPress site was hacked and was redirecting all clicks from Microsoft and Google search results to a some kind of Japanese auto part store.
It was happening for few weeks, during which google Search Console recorded a lot of 404 urls for my website.
A lot, if not all, of those 404 urls have some gibberish in them and ending with some digits.
Here are few examples

```
/40epolymitosis1548027
/9c44d4sunspottedness1569986
/37awald1559460
```

I would like to add a 301 regex redirect for all usrls that end with five or more digits to a homepage.
This is what I have in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 .*\d{5,} /
</IfModule>
```

But that is not working. By the way, I added the regex redirect using Yoast plugin.
In my mind this `RedirectMatch 301 .*\d{5,} /` should redirect all usrl which have 5 or more digits at the end, but it is not working.
Any thoughts/suggestions' on why it's not working?

Comment: The "at the end" part is not currently expressed by your pattern, you need to anchor it at the end for that, using `$`- `.*\d{5,}$`.

Comment: _"By the way, I added the regex redirect using Yoast plugin."_ - and _where_ in the already existing .htaccess configuration did this end up?

Comment: The `RedirectMatch` directive is NOT provided by the rewrite module, but by the alias module. So embedding it in a `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block and prefixing it with a `RewriteEngine on` does not make much sense. Make up your mind which module you want to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an SEO perspective it makes no sense to 301 redirect URLs that were already "correctly" returning a 404 status, to the homepage. Google will only treat these as a soft-404 at best and potentially cause additional problems. A 404 was already the correct response. You could perhaps return a "410 Gone" if these did, at some point, return content with a "200 OK" response status.

The only reason to do anything in `.htaccess` (and return a 404 "early") is to prevent the request being handled by WordPress, which might put unnecessary load on your system.

Since WordPress is already using mod_rewrite (as part of the core WP code block to rewrite URLs to the front-controller), you need to also use mod_rewrite to handle these other URLs. `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive and consequently is processed *later*, despite the apparent order of the directives in the config file.

So, to force a 404 for any URL that ends in 5 digits (or more) then you would add the following at the very top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

```
# Force a 404 for all URLs that end in 5 digits or more
RewriteRule \d{5,}$ - [R=404]
```

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper and you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive (since that already occurs *later* in the file as part of the default WordPress code block).

The `L` flag is not required here.

To return a "410 Gone" instead then change `R=404` to `G`. (To return a "403 Forbidden" then use the `F` flag instead.)

---

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 .*\d{5,} /
> ```

As mentioned above, the `RedirectMatch` belongs to mod_alias, not mod_rewrite. mod_alias is processed later. Since the regex is not *anchored*, `.*\d{5,}` matches any URL-path that simply *contains* at least 5 contiguous digits. The `.*` prefix on the regex is not required.

Comment: How would the final line look like in `.htaccess` for "410 Gone"? I'm little lost with `L, G, F` flags. I uninstalled Yost and installed Redirection plugin in WP, that did the redirection. Looks that the Redirection plugin does the work on `PHP` side, because I do not see anything added in `.htaccess` file. I also changed the regex pattern to `\/\w*\d{5,}` because the earlier pattern also redirected some `cron` request .

Comment: @Guntar You would simply replace the `R=404` flag with `G` (which is a shortcut for `R=410`), ie. `RewriteRule \d{5,}$ - [G]`. "changed the regex pattern to `\/\w*\d{5,}`" - That would be specific to the "Redirection plugin" I assume, since that regex would not work in the `RewriteRule` directive to match the 3 example URLs in your question, since there is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. So, in `.htaccess` the regex would be `^\w+\d{5,}$` or `^(.+/)?\w+\d{5,}$` if expecting URL-paths at different path-depths.

Comment: @Guntar However, you shouldn't necessarily need to modify the regex if using `.htaccess` since the CRON request does not normally trigger an HTTP request so is not subject to the restrictions imposed in `.htaccess`.